# PHP Upload fails for Video but not Image

Tags: php, html, forms, file, video

This form works when i upload an image using it but doesn't work when i upload a video. What do i need to change to upload videos via this form?

```
$videoform = "
    <form action='' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data' name='uploadform'>
        <input name='video' type='file' id='video' >
        <input name='upload' type='submit' id='upload' value=' Upload Video! '>
    </form>";

echo $form;

if($_POST['upload'])
{
    echo $videoform;
}

if(isset($_POST['upload'])) 
{ 
    // define the posted file into variables 
    $name = $_FILES['video']['name']; 
    $tmp_name = $_FILES['video']['tmp_name']; 
    $type = $_FILES['video']['type']; 
    $size = $_FILES['video']['size']; 
    echo $name;
}

echo "<br /><h5>$cname 's Videos</h5>";
?>
```

Comment: Is the video larger than the php.ini settings `post_max_size` or `upload_max_filesize`?  As is there is nothing specific about your code that prevents a video upload vs an image upload.

Comment: What is the size of the video that you are uploading?

Comment: By the way, why did you call your question `Mysql Table index`? It has nothing to do with MySQL.

Comment: I set my php.ini file to ; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
; http://php.net/upload-max-filesize
upload_max_filesize = 200M .......and it still doesn't work

Answer (score 5):

The video may be going over your maximum upload size.  To increase your maximum upload size, add the following lines to your .htaccess file:

```
php_value upload_max_filesize "200M"
php_value post_max_size "200M"
```

(Replace "200M" with whatever you want the maximum to be - "200M" means "200 megabytes".)

Some hosts may not allow you to change those settings, in which case you're out of luck.

These settings can also be changed via your php.ini file, but it's less common for hosts to allow that.

Comment: you could always try `ini_set` for the same values if you can't change the php.ini physically, you can also try to drop a php.ini in the directory of the script that has the above values changed. Various hosts allow different methods, but none of these are garunteeded to work especially if your on a shared host like hostgator or godaddy or yahoo

Comment: Options in order of best solution: `php.ini`, server config (`httpd.conf`), `.htaccess`, `ini_set` inside script.

Comment: I changed my php.ini settings to ; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
; http://php.net/upload-max-filesize
upload_max_filesize = 200M

Comment: @chris - `ini_set` won't work for upload size limits, since those are applied before your script runs.

Comment: @Waggoner_Keith - Does it give an error message?  (Also, you should really only accept answers that work...)

Comment: no there is no error message it just doesn't do anything

Comment: Perhaps you need to enable `error_reporting` and/or `display_errors` in your php.ini?  (Actually, those are things I would use `ini_set` for.)

Comment: I'll bank on your hosting provider having a cap on it at a higher level than you have access to, despite what you set where it appears its going to override it if nothing else is working. I know hostgater has such logic implimented, as does godaddy. Chances are if you went to a top 10 list of hosting providers that are cheap, then you found yourself a hosting provider that also limits your access outside of "look ma I made a website".

Comment: @Brilliand, you place an ini_set above everything else in a given PHP file and it will apply that to the PHP in question as your right it loads before the script just like the .ini loads before all scripts, but hierarchy takes place ini loads first, then any settings you make at a script level, the whole point of that ability is to be able to change needs on scripts that require it with out effecting the whole php install